# What is purpose of reset.css & text.css in 960 Grid CSS?

Tags: css, 960.gs

I'm newbie to 960 Grid CSS & I found in some tutorial's that I need to use **reset.css** & **text.css**

Can anyone explain actual purpose of these two files?

Comment: A reset.css file typically overrides a browsers' typical style behaviour.

Comment: As far as purpose, they usually make all elements equal, as opposed to the "standard" way elements may be displayed according to a browser's standard style file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric Meyer's CSS Reset (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)is a very popular example, and one I use fairly religiously. Like @Jared points out, it "overrides the browser's typical style behavior". What that should mean to you (as it does me) is that regardless of browser, all of my input fields will have the same margin, padding, borders, etc. All of my `<p>` tags will have behave the same - they've all been "reset" to take on NO default style based on the browser rendering the page....I have to tell EVERYTHING how to look, behave, etc.

I have no idea what text.css is - unless that's a separate CSS file for all of my @font-face usage, which is what I do (and would recommend to anyone).

HTH